# C# Byte[] to long reverse not working

Tags: c#, arrays, long-integer, bitconverter

Why is this program not working? I convert a byte array to long. Then from the long I convert back to a byte array. The resulting byte array is not the same as original.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] myBytes = { 0, 0, 0, 32, 56, 99, 87, 34, 56, 56, 34, 33, 67
                         , 56, 66, 72, 1, 0, 0, 56, 0, 22};

        long data = BitConverter.ToInt64(myBytes, 0);

        byte[] byteData = BitConverter.GetBytes(data);

        Console.WriteLine("byte array: " + BitConverter.ToString(myBytes));
        Console.WriteLine("byte array: " + BitConverter.ToString(byteData));
    }
}
```

Comment: As method name(`ToInt64`) implies a `long` is 64 bit(8 bytes) long.

Comment: It's not *not working* but *not works as you expected*.

Comment: Aye you have 22 bytes in that array, int64 is 8. Why are you converting to a long anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of bytes exceed a `long` can hold(8 bytes, 64 bits).

For alternative solution, I'd suggest to use [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) if your target framework is higher than(including) .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 5):

Since [l4V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906557/i4v) already [gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752672/c-sharp-byte-to-long-reverse-not-working#comment24131691_16752672) the right assumption, I just want to add it as an aswer but I think my answer doesn't deserve any votes since all upvotes should go to [l4V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906557/i4v). Upvote his comment.

From [`BitConverter.ToInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64.aspx)

> The `ToInt64` method converts the bytes from index **startIndex** to
>   **startIndex + 7** to a Int64 value.

So basicly, this conversations takes only `8` bytes (`0, 0, 0, 32, 56, 99, 87, 34`) of your `byte` array. Other bytes of your array are ignored at this situation.