# Convert byte array represented for sql_variant typed column value to long/int64

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-variant

I have a byte array value of 10 elements taken from an `sql_variant` column in my database table and would like to convert it to a long value. I tried this.

```
 byte []a = new byte[10]{ 127, 1, 0, 202, 154, 59, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
 long i = BitConverter.ToInt64(a, 0);
 Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
```

but it's not giving me the correct result. I expect it to be `10000000000`.

Thank you if you could offer me some ideas of classes or methods in C# I can look up into.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Byte\[\] to long reverse not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752672/c-sharp-byte-to-long-reverse-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

10000000000 in a hex notation is 02540BE400.

Byte array for this value in reverse order is:

```
byte[] a = new byte[10] { 0x00, 0xE4, 0x0B, 0x54, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

or in a decimal notation:

```
byte[] a = new byte[10] { 0, 228, 11, 84, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

For this array your function returns expected result: 10000000000.